# How I can hold terminal over window when start a program from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this bash script and its works, but when my bash open a program, the program start over my terminal. How I can hold my terminal over my windows. (like superimpose window or z-index)

thanks for advice.

```
case $option in
1) #start xampp and sublimetext
    sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
    banner_web_developer
    subl
    ask_music
;;
2) #open netbeans and start xampp
    banner_java
    nohup /bin/sh "/home/quethzel/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans" &
    sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
    ask_music
;;
3) # call the copyleft function
    clear;
    copyleft
;;
```

Comment: check this question here http://superuser.com/questions/142945/bash-command-to-focus-a-specific-window

Comment: What desktop are your using? You may be able to accomplish what you need with DCOP/DBUS calls to your terminal main window. Just type `dbus` into your terminal (or for Trinity/kde3, type `dcop`). You will get an active list of protocol enabled apps returned if either dbus or dcop are available.

Comment: Thanks bro, I solved adding sleep 0.2 and wmctrl -R Terminal; after start the aplication. It's works